# Vaadin 14 (Flow) - Binding - where can I get access to .setAsRequired(boolean)

Tags: vaadin14

As title.   I am working on a Vaadin 14 application (final stages of upgrading from Vaadin 7).

One of the aspects I am currently looking at is updating some existing fields on a screen to control whether or not to enforce mandatory (asRequired) checks.
ie: if field A is populated, field B is mandatory, otherwise not mandatory.   That kind of thing.

Looking at the API, it appears I should be able to do this.
https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.5.1/com/vaadin/flow/data/binder/Binder.Binding.html

```
void setAsRequiredEnabled(boolean asRequiredEnabled)
Enable or disable asRequired validator. The validator is enabled by default.
```

The problem is, I cannot seem to find where I can get access to this function.
We are currently using Vaadin version 14.5.1.

The Binder and the Binding Builder both do not show this function.

I would appreciate any guidance.  I just cannot seem to locate how to access this function, to control dynamic adjustments to the required validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, right after I posted the query, it took me slightly longer in experimenting with the Flow API to find the solution.

For anyone else trying to find this -
I found you get the Binding object from the Binder you are using as follows, which then can tweak this setting:

```
Binding binding = (Binding) binder.getBinding("property").get();
binding.setAsRequiredEnabled(true);
```